# Exactly how do I stream a camera to a specific URI dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, modx, modx-revolution

I have obtained this sample code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="stuff, to, help, search, engines, not" name="keywords">
<meta content="What this page is about." name="description">
<meta content="Display Webcam Stream" name="title">
<title>Display Webcam Stream</title>

<style>
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    border: 10px #333 solid;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #666;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

    </video>
</div>
<script>
    var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
    }

    function handleVideo(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    }

    function videoError(e) {
        // do something
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This lets me see myself, using my camera. Great! But how do I stream that dynamically to a URI like "/username/live"?

Please forgive my absolute ignorance in this area.

I imagine that I could setup a PHP page that gets the URI and checks if that user is in-fact online and allowing access to their camera, but I have no Idea how to implement such sorcery.

If the user is NOT allowing access to their camera, I would like to show their profile page, which is easy peasy.

I'm using MODX Revolution 2.4.2 with the user URLs extra, so maybe that information will be helpful.

Comment: well you have to start reading about webRTC if you dont want to reinvent youtube :)

Comment: WebRTC seems so limited and bad at scaling after taking your advice. Also not good for mobile devices. So, should I use websockets instead?

Comment: You have to transfer videostream between users. If you do it through your server you will have to have veery large bandwidth and if you use webRTC you don't need your server to transfer streem at all. C the difference?

Comment: Sure I see that difference, but webRTC kills phone batteries, is highly limited, very inefficient, and seems to be bad for mobile to mobile, or mobile to web communications. I wish I could find a code example of each, webRTC, and websockets, so I could compare them side by side.

Comment: Websockets is `from another opera` as people in Russia say. You won't need websockets in anycase I think. Videostream is a part of html5, so when you create your own playback server (Ireally doubt you would) you can use regular mp4 files to stream.